# My understanding about the non-restrictive use of the relative clause in a partcular sentence

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, non-restrictive

Almost every chinese who works at an iPhone manifacture in China usually uses a china-produced phone, which is way cheaper.

I just want to make sure if my understanding especially about the non-restrictive use of the relative clause in the sentence above is correct.

What I understand about it is "china-produced phones are generally (or usually or most of the times or all the times) way cheaper than iPhones."

Do I understand correct?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The pronoun is ambiguous. *Which* could be referring to:

- phones produced in China,
- an iPhone manufacturer in China that uses phones produced in China, or
- Chinese workers at iPhone manufacturers in China who use phones produced in China.

It could be referring to the phones themselves, or it could be referring to the cost of the labour.

In fact, it's also not clear if *usually uses* is referring to the manufacturer or every Chinese worker at the manufacturer.

Nor is it clear if there is only a single, specific manufacturer or if the sentence is talking about manufacturers in general.

In short, not only is *which* ambiguous, but so are other parts of the sentence. This makes it impossible to say exactly what is being said.

We can say that *something* is cheaper *somewhere*, and it involves phones produced in China, but that's all we can interpret from the individual sentence as it's written.

Comment: sorry I made many other mistakes on it.Based on what you pointed at, I guess now it would be sentence in which I can finally talk only about that which if I change to : Almost every chinese workers who works at an iPhone manifacture in China usually uses a china-produced phone, which is way cheaper than an iPhone.

Comment: @TomTomTom Yes. With that edit (especially *way cheaper* ***than an iPhone***), it's clear that the pronoun is referring to phones produced in China.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then again though..I just want to make sure if my understanding especially about the non-restrictive use of the relative clause in the sentence above is correct.

What I understand about it is "china-produced phones are generally (or usually or most of the times or all the times) way cheaper than iPhones."

Do I understand correct? Thank you!

Comment: @TomTomTom No, not quite. The statement after the comma is that phones produced in China *are* cheaper, not that they are *usually* cheaper. Your (revised) sentence seems to imply that workers usually use them *because* they are cheaper.

Comment: Thank you for your comment again! Well, is there a difference in meaning between ''phones produced in China are cheaper'' and ''phones produced in China are usually cheaper''?

Comment: Yes. The first statement is an absolute (you can assume a missing *always*), while the second is similar to a probability (*often* or *have a greater chance of being*)..

Comment: Sorry for late..Thank you.So, china-produced phones are (always) way cheaper than iPhones.